# Question on quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hamiltonian, fourier-transform

I saw on Ryder's "*Quantum Field Theory*" book in chapter 7 where he writes down the hamiltonian of a real scalar field as
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
H&=\int d^3x[(1/2)(\partial_t \phi)^2+(1/2) (\nabla \phi)^2+(1/2)M^2(\phi)^2] \\
&=\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3 2E_k} \frac 12 E_k(a^*(k)a(k)+a(k)a^*(k))]\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

My question is how did the second step came from first step,where did $d^3x$ go and $d^3k$ cam and from where a and a* came and also shouldnt the $E_k$ should cancel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You substitute the Fourier mode expression  $$
\phi(x)= \int \frac{d^3k}{2E_k (2\pi)^3}( a_k e^{-ikx}+ a^* e^{ikx})
$$ where $kx= -{\bf k}\cdot {\bf x}+ E_k t$
and
$$
[a_k, a^*_{k'}]= 2E_k (2\pi)^3 \delta^3({\bf k}-{\bf k}')
$$

and do the integrals using
$$
\int \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} e^{i{\bf k}\cdot ({\bf x}- {\bf x}')} 
= \delta^3 ({\bf x}- {\bf x}')\quad \int {d^3x}e^{i{\bf x}\cdot ({\bf k}- {\bf k}')} = (2\pi)^3 \delta^3 ({\bf k}- {\bf k}')
$$

You could cancel the  $E_k$, but it makes little sense to do so as  it's best to keep the Lorentz Invariant phase space measure $d^3k/(2E (2\pi)^3)$ s explicit.

Comment: Can you show the steps please?

Comment: I dont have the book to hand, but surely the mode expansaion of $\phi(x,t)$ is given somewhere? After that doing the $x$ integrals is "plug and chug"  with the usual Fourier expansions of the delta functions.  It takes a page or two, so I'd rather not write it all out when it must be in the book.

Comment: In the book,the steps are not shown thats why,can you just show 2 or 3 steps,please?

Comment: I added a bit more.

Comment: Thank you so much